# Load file contents before any transformation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to use Webpack with React to build a documentation site, and I'd like to be able to show the example code alongside the example. I'd rather do this dynamically so I never forget to sync up, but I'd rather it not be a separate step in the build process. Of course, I figured I couldn't do this at run-time with `fs.readFile` or something for a number of reasons (it would be browser-side and the file wouldn't exist anyways).

So I thought I'd try `raw-loader`. That gave me the post-babel result, which is... better than nothing, but I want the original source. `raw-text-loader` gave me the same thing. Is there anything I can do to get the original source code?

Is there anything I can do to get the t

Comment: One resource I've got is the Semantic UI React docs which are great. They do this at runtime. https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/docs/app/Components/ComponentDoc/ComponentExample.js so in case this never gets an answer and someone needs to do this, that's better than nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, maybe not the most intelligent thing, but I had to import using

`import ExampleText from '!raw!./Example.js'`

instead of

`import ExampleText from 'raw!./Example.js'`

Sorry if that was obvious. =)